# Recuperar Valor BigDecimal de @PathParam

Tags: java, restful, vraptor

Tenho a seguinte chamada

```
http://localhost:8080/app-teste/produto/1234/76.60
```

e quero recuperar assim:

```
@Get("/{produtoDto.codBarras}/{preco}")
public void produtoComPreco(ProdutoDto produtoDto, @PathParam("preco") 
BigDecimal preco) {
System.out.println(preco); // imprime 7660
```

...

no entanto  o ponto do preco=76.60 some e fica apenas 7660

Tem como manter esse ponto?

Estou usando VRAPTOR.

Comment: Já tentou passar o valor com uma vírgula? Talvez seja alguma configuração de `Locale`.

Answer (score 0):

O converter para `BigDecimal` do VRaptor está esperando uma vírgula para casas decimais por causa do Locale do seu servidor (que é provavelmente `pt-BR`).
Se você fizer a sua chamada assim: `http://localhost:8080/app-teste/produto/1234/76,60` ele deve converter corretamente, porém eu não te recomendo deixar assim.

O que você pode fazer é receber uma `String` e fazer a conversão para `BigDecimal` normalmente

```
@Get("/{produtoDto.codBarras}/{preco}")
public void produtoComPreco(ProdutoDto produtoDto, @PathParam("preco") 
String preco) {
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(preco));
}
```

Você pode tentar fazer o ajuste do Locale porém ele deve estar configurado para `pt-BR`, de acordo com o seu server, e alterar para outro locale pode influenciar em toda a sua aplicação.

Outra solução seria sobrescrever o converter de BigDecimal, se você achar necessário.

Segue um link de uma pessoa que passou por esse problema: http://www.guj.com.br/t/resolvido-vraptor-3-4-1-problema-com-converter/298683/2

E um link de uma issue relacionada: https://github.com/caelum/vraptor4/issues/504

Comment: Show. Obrigado! Vou receber como String e converter. Muito obrigado, Explicação boa demais!!!